# How to add custom type to selected option for onChange event in React-Select

Tags: typescript, onchange, react-select

I created a SelectBox component using react-select and added onChange event for it.
I would like to add a type "SelectedItemType" to the selected option in onChange event.
However the onChnage event is of type
(property) onChange?: ((newValue: unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta) => void) | undefined
Hence the option type is unknown and its preventing me from adding types other than unknown which makes it difficult to extract the object attributes from option

```
import { ForwardedRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import Select, { SelectInstance } from "react-select";

export type SelectedItemType = {
value: string;
label: string;
};

export type SelectProps = {
options: SelectedItemType[];
ref?: ForwardedRef<SelectInstance>;
onChange: (selectedItem: unknown) => void;
};

const SelectBox: React.FC<SelectProps> = forwardRef<
SelectInstance,
SelectProps
>(({ options, onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
return (
<Select
options={options}
ref={ref}
{...props}
onChange={(newValue: unknown) => onChange(newValue)}
/>
);
});

export default SelectBox;
```

In the above code I would like to add SelectedItemType to the newValue for onChange. However its throwing an error saying
Type '(newValue: SelectedItemType) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValue: unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta) => void'.
Types of parameters 'newValue' and 'newValue' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'SelectedItemType'.
How do I add this custom Type to the option as I want to extract the value and label from the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to assign type to `newValue` to `SelectedItemType` so that its properties can be easily accessed in `onChange` function then it can be done by doing two main changes.

1. Change type of `onChange` property of `SelectProps` as

```js
export type SelectProps = {
  options: SelectedItemType[];
  ref?: ForwardedRef<SelectInstance>;
  onChange: (selectedItem: SelectedItemType) => void;
};
```

2. Then in `select` component its `onChange` would be modified as

```js
<Select
      options={options}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
      onChange={(newValue: unknown) => onChange(newValue as SelectedItemType)}
    />
```

Then use your `SelectBox` component like:

```js
<SelectBox
        options={[
          { label: "A", value: "1" },
          { label: "B", value: "2" }
        ]}
        onChange={function (selectedItem: SelectedItemType): void {
          console.log(selectedItem.value);
        }}
      />
```

Here is full code for file `App.tsx`

```js
import { ForwardedRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import Select, { SelectInstance } from "react-select";

export type SelectedItemType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

export type SelectProps = {
  options: SelectedItemType[];
  ref?: ForwardedRef<SelectInstance>;
  onChange: (selectedItem: SelectedItemType) => void;
};

const SelectBox: React.FC<SelectProps> = forwardRef<
  SelectInstance,
  SelectProps
>(({ options, onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
      onChange={(newValue: unknown) => onChange(newValue as SelectedItemType)}
    />
  );
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectBox
        options={[
          { label: "A", value: "1" },
          { label: "B", value: "2" }
        ]}
        onChange={function (selectedItem: SelectedItemType): void {
          console.log(selectedItem.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```